# How to know the origins of the result of shapely's symmetric_difference?

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely, overlay, symmetric-difference

Suppose I have two line geometries:

```
import shapely 

line1 = shapely.geometry.LineString([(0, 0), (2, 0)])
line2 = shapely.geometry.LineString([(1, 0), (3, 0)])

shapely.symmetric_difference(line1, line2).wkt
# 'MULTILINESTRING ((0 0, 1 0), (2 0, 3 0))'
```

The result of the `symmetric_difference` operation gives me exactly what I expect: the parts of the geometries that only belong to one of the two original inputs.

However, there is no immediate way to know which "piece" belonged to which input geometry.
Using the example above, it's obvious that the `((0,0),(1,0))` segment was from `line1` and that the `((2,0),(3,0))` segment was from `line2`. But how can I extract that information from the results?
Would it be possible to get something like a structured output that lets the user know which one they originated from? Something like this:

```
shapely.symmetric_difference_with_origins(line1, line2)
# ['LINESTRING (0 0, 1 0)', 'LINESTRING (2 0, 3 0)']
```

In this case, the first item in the output list would show you the parts that came from the first input (`line1`) and the second item in the output list would show you the parts that came from the second input (`line2`).

### What I've tried

I tried using Geopandas' `symmetric difference` method, expecting it would give me a type of outer-join table of some sort, but that didn't work:

```
import geopandas as gpd

df1 = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'id1':[1],
                        'geometry':[line1]},
                       crs="epsg:4326")

df2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'id2':[2],
                        'geometry':[line2]},
                       crs="epsg:4326")

df1.symmetric_difference(df2)
# 0    MULTILINESTRING ((0 0, 1 0), (2 0, 3 0))
# dtype: geometry
```

The output of GeoPandas' `symmetric_difference` method is just a GeoSeries, not a whole GeoDataFrame. And it only has one element in it with the two "pieces" in one multi-part geometry.

### Back to my main question

How can I perform a symmetric difference calculation between two geometries that gives me the mapping between the pieces/parts of the output and the two inputs?

Comment: Perhaps you could compute differences A-B and B-A separately instead of using symmetric difference.

Comment: Thanks for the idea! I considered writing a solution that would do this, but it felt like a weird solution. I also felt like there was another very similar command to do this exact thing I'm asking. And it turns out there is, as indicated in [@user2856](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/2856/user2856)'s [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/462363/123828).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`overlay()` method](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/user_guide/set_operations.html):

```py
from shapely.geometry import LineString
import geopandas as gp

line1 = LineString([(0, 0), (2, 0)])
line2 = LineString([(1, 0), (3, 0)])

a = gp.GeoDataFrame({'geometry': [line1], 'id1': [1]})
b = gp.GeoDataFrame({'geometry': [line2], 'id2': [2]})

c = a.overlay(b, how='symmetric_difference')

print(c.head())
```

```sh
   id1  id2  geometry
0  1.0  NaN  LINESTRING (0.0 0.0, 1.0 0.0)
1  NaN  2.0  LINESTRING (2.0 0.0, 3.0 0.0)
```

Comment: Yes!!! This is exactly it!!! Thank you!!!